# SublimeText3 Jedi autocomplete plugin does not recognize virtualenv Python path

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I've installed and configured Jedi autocomplete v0.12.0 on Sublime Text 3 v3.1.1. In Jedi user settings, I've set `python_interpreter` to point to python version in `virtualenvs`.

```
"python_interpreter": "/home/username/.virtualenvs/cv3/bin/python"
```

The problem is that in [`/dependencies/jedi/api/environment.py`](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/jedi/api/environment.html), the method `_assert_safe` does not recognize the virtualenv path as safe.

```
def _assert_safe(executable_path, safe):
    if safe and not _is_safe(executable_path):
        raise InvalidPythonEnvironment(
            "The python binary is potentially unsafe.")
```

The `_assert_safe` method calls the method `def _is_safe(executable_path)` which also returns false. The code in these two methods is pretty simple and I understand what is happening, I just don't see any solution. For testing purposes I added the `virtualenv` Python path to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: If you are sure it is safe, you should probably just use safe=False and everything will be working. Not sure how to do that with SublimeText3, but that's my take on it.

Comment: @DaveHalter I don't think hard coding the value is a good solution. However, I solved this problem by launching Sublime from terminal under the virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I could find was to launch `Sublime` from terminal under the `virtualenv`. In terminal:

```
$ workon virtualenv_name
$ subl
```

Now `_is_safe(executable_path)` method can find `virtualenv` Python executable and returns `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Jedi checks if interpreters are safe. While it's perfectly reasonable for you to use whatever environment you want, it's a bit hard sometimes to argue if it's safe or not. You can just use `create_environment(path, safe=False)` when you use Jedi, but obviously this sublime plugin doesn't allow that (but maybe should?).

IMO a better solution would be to create venv's instead of virtualenvs. Those work better with Jedi, because they are not copying the whole Python binary (which does not make a lot of sense anyway). I'm not 100% sure this helps you, but it might help some other people.